# Drools EscapeQuotes settings

Tags: drools

Where we can change below in Drools application. I am new to Drools.

EscapeQuotes: Can be "true" or "false". If "true", then quotation marks are escaped so that they appear literally in the DRL. If omitted, quotation marks are escaped.

I found this article as well, but figuring out where we need to make the changes for it.

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/drools/getting-started-with-decision-tables-in-drools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes in the RuleSet area of the decision table definition.

From the docs:

> 16.7.2.1. RuleSet definitions
>
> Entries in the RuleSet area of a decision table define DRL constructs and rule attributes that you want to apply to all rules in a package (not only in the spreadsheet). Entries must be in a vertically stacked sequence of cell pairs, where the first cell contains a label and the cell to the right contains the value. A decision table spreadsheet can have only one RuleSet area.
>
> The following table lists the supported labels and values for RuleSet definitions:
>
> | Label | Value | Usage |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | EscapeQuotes | true or false. If true, then quotation marks are escaped so that they appear literally in the DRL. | Optional, at most once. If omitted, quotation marks are escaped. |

For future reference, you should be referencing the [official documentation](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#decision-tables-rule-set-entries-ref) and not random sites on the internet. The Drools folks have amazingly good documentation compared to some other libraries, and the library is actively enough developed that by the time a book or blog is published, it's likely out of date or incomplete.